# CD strange behaviour

Tags: windows, cmd, cd

I need somebody to explain me what is happening in this sequence of "cd.." commands (note there is no space between "cd" and "..") :

```
c:\sebas\miscosas\escacs\pgns\$_ya\2018_08_sants>cd..

c:\sebas\miscosas\escacs\pgns\$_ya>cd..

c:\sebas\miscosas\escacs\pgns>cd..

c:\sebas\miscosas\escacs>cd..

c:\sebas\miscosas>cd..
'cd..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I did write "cd.." just once, and later I use "arrow up" to recover previous command.

Why is it failing on 5-th time ?

The OpSys is Windows Server 2008 R2, version 6.1, build 7601.

Thanks

By the way, if I use "cd .." (with a space between "cd" and ".."), then all goes fine.

Comment: mr Mofi - my question was not "why cd..' works", but "why 'cd..' does not work at fifth try" ...

Comment: it works on directory "c:\sebas\miscosas\escacs\pgns\$_ya\2018_08_sants"

Comment: it works on directory "c:\sebas\miscosas\escacs\pgns\$_ya"

Comment: it works on directory "c:\sebas\miscosas\escacs\pgns"

Comment: it works on directory "c:\sebas\miscosas\escacs"

Comment: it fails in directory "c:\sebas\miscosas"

Comment: buff ... there was a file named "cd" in that directory ! THANKS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`cd..` is wrong syntax and works just by chance.

The right syntax is: **command**<kbd>SPACE</kbd>*argument*

The **command** is `cd` and the *argument* is the relative path `..\`.

But `cmd.exe` searches first for a file with name `cd` on using `cd..` because it interprets `cd..` as mistyped file name and not as internal command **CD**. And Windows command processor tries to run found file when there is in current directory really a file with name `cd` as it is obviously the case for directory `c:\sebas\miscosas`.

The two dots at end of `cd..` are removed by `cmd.exe` on searching for a suitable directory entry. Removing trailing spaces/tabs and trailing dots is nearly always done as part of an error correction as it can be seen on running the command line:

```
echo Hello world!>"cd..  "
```

This command line creates a file with name `cd` without the two dots and the two spaces at end.

See also DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) which is about the same issue.

And see also Microsoft article about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

The usage of `cd..\` works even if there is a file with name `cd` in current directory. But this command line is nevertheless using wrong syntax and works again only by chance. If there would be a file with name `cd.` in current directory, this command line would fail again because of `cmd.exe` searches now for a file with name `cd.` in current directory.

So in future use command **CD** only with right syntax: `cd ..\`

Comment: CMD reads up to the first delimiter not space alone to get the command. See `dir/a/b`. `dir.` and `dir..`.

Comment: @CatCat That's true, but `.` is not an argument separator for Windows command processor. Horizontal tab (0x09), vertical tab (0x0B), form-feed (0x0C), normal space (0x20), comma (0x2C) semicolon (0x3B), equal sign (0x3D) and no-break space (0xFF in OEM code pages) are argument separators as written by Dave Benham in [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/3074564) I am quite sure that nobody typing commands in command prompt window uses intentionally any other argument separator than normal space. `cd..` is definitely wrong.

Comment: @CatCat `dir/a/b` is also of wrong syntax. Windows command processor interprets `/` first as beginning of an option and therefore auto-corrects and interprets it as `dir /a /b`. But forward slash could be also interpreted as directory separator within a file/folder argument string. That does not happen on usage of `dir/a/b`, but it is no advisable to run commands on which `cmd.exe` needs to auto-correct the syntax as in some use cases the auto-correction could result in an execution behavior not expected by the user as the `cd..` example demonstrates.

Comment: I use `command/?` all the time. Forward slash to backslash is done last and recently added. Type `cd\\`. Dave whoever is not 100% right.

Comment: And it is not advisable. Rules only seem to apply to switches and command name only. Subsequent parameters must act normal except switches.